# Mysql: xor a string with a key

Tags: mysql, string, bit-manipulation, xor

I want to Bitwise-XOR a string (actually its binary representation) with a KEY.

The result of the operation should be represented as HEX.

What I have: 
'a' - the UTF-8 String to be changed.
'ACF123456' - the key in HEX.

Result seen as BIGINT:

```
select CONV(HEX('a'), 16, 10)  ^  CONV('ACF123456', 16, 10);
```

Result seen as HEX:

```
select CONV( CONV(HEX('a'), 16, 10)  ^  CONV('ACF123456', 16, 10), 10, 16);
```

Questions:

1. Is the conversion above done correctly?
2. What happens if the string is too long (i.e instead of 'a' we have 'a veeeeeery long string')? It seems that the conv() function has a limitation (is it the 64-bit precision from the documentation)? And besides the XOR operator ^ has also a limitation, related to the nr. of bits of the returned result. Any solutions that work for any string (a stored procedure is allowed)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conversions look fine to me.
And as you point out, both [`CONV()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_conv) and [`^`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-xor) have indeed a 64-bits precision.

2^64 = 16^16, therefore strings of more than 16 hexadecimal digits *should* convert to integers larger than 2^64. However, such strings will be brutally (silently) truncated from the left when attempting to convert them to integers.

The point of my solution here is to slice such strings. Obviously, the result may not be displayed as an integer, but only as a string representation.

*Let* `@input` *be your "string to be changed" and* `@key`, *your "key".*

1. Assign `HEX(@input)` to `@hex_input`. No problem here since `HEX()` works with strings.
2. Slice `@hex_input` into 16 hexadecimal digit long strings, starting from the right
3. Likewise, slice `@key` into 16 digit long strings.
4. Compute the `X-OR` of each 64-bit slice of `@hex_input` with each 64-bit slice of `@key`, starting from the right. Use `CONV(@slice, 16, 10)`. If either `@hex_input` or `@key` has less slices than the other string, then `X-OR` the remaining slices of the other string with 0.
5. Convert each 64-bit number resulting from the `X-OR` in point 4. back into an hexadecimal string with `UNHEX()`.
6. Reassemble the resulting slices. This is your result.

A three-columns `TEMPORARY` table could be used as an array to store slices of `@hex_input`, `@mask` and the resulting slices.

Put this all together into a stored procedure, and *voilà*!

You sound like you have some skills in MySQL, you should be able to translate the above into real code. But I'll be happy to help if you need further guidance.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the conversion above done correctly?

No, the operands are of different sizes, if the size of the string is known, you have given the remainder of the key to a possible attacker.

```
select HEX(CONV(HEX('a'), 16, 10)  ^  CONV('ACF123456', 16, 10));
```

returns:

'ACF123437'

Part of the key is clearly present in the output:

'ACF1234'

The rest:

```
HEX(HEX('a') ^ 0x56)
```

returns:

'37'

If the key is only used once(one time pad) or the data is a fixed sized string or (the non-repeating key length is equal to or larger than the data possible **and** knowing the length of the data is not an issue.) Then this type of solution would be fine.

**But** if the same key was applied to an entire column with variable length data, statistical analysis can be applied greatly reducing the search space, especially if the person has any previous knowledge of the data.

---

> Any solutions that work for any string:

Starting with MySql 8, but not MariaDB as of 11.3, you can use the bit-wise, AND OR XOR NOT(`&`,`|`,`^`,`~` respectively), operators on the `BINARY()` data type to produce a result larger than 64 bits.

The operands must be the same size. The cast will [0 pad to fill the size difference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast).

Care must be taken to ensure the data and key are the same size as any length discrepancies will output the original data or key since any value xor'ed with 0 gives the original data. The concerns are expressed above.

```
select CAST('a' as BINARY(1)) ^  CAST(0xACF123456 as BINARY(1));
```

returns a `BINARY(1)` containing 0xCD: 0x61 ^ 0xAC

Note the order of truncation, `AC` and not `56` which may not match expected results from other languages, platforms, or previous usage(i.e. the posted code). Reverse the byte order(0x563412CF0A) if compatibility is needed.

You can `HEX` the results:

```
select HEX(CAST('Hello World!' as BINARY(12)) ^ CAST(0xACF123456ACF123456ACF123 as BINARY(12)));
```

'E4944F2905EF455B24C09502'

Reversing (note the added `0x` to the above string):

```
select CAST(CAST(0xE4944F2905EF455B24C09502 as BINARY(12)) ^ CAST(0xACF123456ACF123456ACF123 as BINARY(12)) as CHAR(12));
```

'Hello World!'

### Restrictions

The `BINARY(n)` size `n` is expressed as the number of bytes, therefore the data and key must align to 8 bits. The non-aligned key of `ACF123456` would need to become `ACF1234560` or `0ACF123456` to meet the alignment requirement.

Note: the fulfillment in the byte reversal as described above is given by the '0A' in '0x563412CF0A'.

This solution is effective for known length strings or dynamically generated SQL statements since the `size` passed to `Binary(size)` cannot be a function or parameter.